# Error during using Google OAuth in Next auth

Tags: reactjs, google-cloud-platform, next.js, google-oauth, next-auth

I have developed an application in nextjs13 and have used google provider and credentials provider with mongo (prisma as ORM) for authentication. the credentials provider works fine but the google provider is giving me an error which is not visible in console or network tab. When I log in then the login screen by google appears and then when I click on the account then it redirects me to the homepage but in the url it gives me an error.

url after logging in - https://stayscape.vercel.app/?callbackUrl=https%3A%2F%2Fstayscape.vercel.app%2F%3FcallbackUrl%3Dhttps%253A%252F%252Fstayscape.vercel.app%252F%26error%3DCallback&error=Callback

when I checked logs it showed me this error - [next-auth][error][adapter_error_getUserByAccount]
https://next-auth.js.org/errors#adapter_error_getuserbyaccount
Invalid `prisma.account.findUnique()` invocation:

```
Inconsistent query result: Field user is required to return data, got `null` instead. {
  message: '\n' +
    'Invalid `prisma.account.findUnique()` invocation:\n' +
    '\n' +
    '\n' +
    'Inconsistent query result: Field user is required to return data, got `null` instead.',
  stack: 'Error: \n' +
    'Invalid `prisma.account.findUnique()` invocation:\n' +
    '\n' +
    '\n' +
    'Inconsistent query result: Field user is required to return data, got `null` instead.\n' +
    '    at Zr.handleRequestError (/var/task/node_modules/@prisma/client/runtime/library.js:171:6587)\n' +
    '    at Zr.handleAndLogRequestError (/var/task/node_modules/@prisma/client/runtime/library.js:171:5948)\n' +
    '    at Zr.request (/var/task/node_modules/@prisma/client/runtime/library.js:171:5786)\n' +
    '    at async t._request (/var/task/node_modules/@prisma/client/runtime/library.js:174:10455)\n' +
    '    at async getUserByAccount (/var/task/node_modules/@next-auth/prisma-adapter/dist/index.js:11:29)',
  name: 'Error'
}
[next-auth][error][OAUTH_CALLBACK_HANDLER_ERROR] 
https://next-auth.js.org/errors#oauth_callback_handler_error 
Invalid `prisma.account.findUnique()` invocation:


Inconsistent query result: Field user is required to return data, got `null` instead. Error: 
Invalid `prisma.account.findUnique()` invocation:


Inconsistent query result: Field user is required to return data, got `null` instead.
    at Zr.handleRequestError (/var/task/node_modules/@prisma/client/runtime/library.js:171:6587)
    at Zr.handleAndLogRequestError (/var/task/node_modules/@prisma/client/runtime/library.js:171:5948)
    at Zr.request (/var/task/node_modules/@prisma/client/runtime/library.js:171:5786)
    at async t._request (/var/task/node_modules/@prisma/client/runtime/library.js:174:10455)
    at async getUserByAccount (/var/task/node_modules/@next-auth/prisma-adapter/dist/index.js:11:29) {
  name: 'GetUserByAccountError',
  code: undefined
}
```

I expected it to log in as credentials provider is doing it.

1. I have checked the urls at the gcp.
   here's the file structure of my application -
   [File structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xiVy5.png)

Here's my code

```
import bcrypt from "bcrypt"
import NextAuth, { AuthOptions } from "next-auth"
import CredentialsProvider from "next-auth/providers/credentials"
import GithubProvider from "next-auth/providers/github"
import GoogleProvider from "next-auth/providers/google"
import { PrismaAdapter } from "@next-auth/prisma-adapter"

import prisma from "@/app/libs/prismadb"

export const authOptions: AuthOptions = {
  adapter: PrismaAdapter(prisma),
  providers: [
    GithubProvider({
      clientId: process.env.GITHUB_ID as string,
      clientSecret: process.env.GITHUB_SECRET as string
    }),
    GoogleProvider({
      clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID as string,
      clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET as string
    }),
    CredentialsProvider({
      name: 'credentials',
      credentials: {
        email: { label: 'email', type: 'text' },
        password: { label: 'password', type: 'password' }
      },
      async authorize(credentials) {
        if (!credentials?.email || !credentials?.password) {
          throw new Error('Invalid credentials');
        }

        const user = await prisma.user.findUnique({
          where: {
            email: credentials.email
          }
        });

        if (!user || !user?.hashedPassword) {
          throw new Error('Invalid credentials');
        }

        const isCorrectPassword = await bcrypt.compare(
          credentials.password,
          user.hashedPassword
        );

        if (!isCorrectPassword) {
          throw new Error('Invalid credentials');
        }

        return user;
      }
    })
  ],
  pages: {
    signIn: '/',
  },
  debug: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development',
  session: {
    strategy: "jwt",
  },
  secret: process.env.NEXTAUTH_SECRET,
}

export default NextAuth(authOptions);
```